# Display column value as table header rather than its original one

Tags: php, mysql

I got a database in mySQL, let says "Storage" with a table in it called "Storage_Det". Here is the content of "Storage_Det":

```
valueid | formid |  submissionid |  fieldname  |  fieldvalue
--------+--------+---------------+-------------+-------------
1       | 1      |  1            |  name       |  Alex
2       | 1      |  1            |  position   |  Manager
3       | 1      |  1            |  room       |  3-10
4       | 1      |  2            |  name       |  Ben
5       | 1      |  2            |  position   |  Accountant
6       | 1      |  2            |  room       |  2-05
7       | 1      |  3            |  name       |  Denny
8       | 1      |  3            |  position   |  Marketing
9       | 1      |  3            |  room       |  1-03
```

There's no problem for me to display it with php. My problem is: I want to display "name", "position", and "room" for my new table view so that it will show like this:

```
submissionid | name   | position   | room |
-------------+--------+------------+------+
1            | Alex   | Manager    | 3-10 |
2            | Ben    | Accountant | 2-05 |
3            | Denny  | Marketing  | 1-03 |
```

Since I am a newbie here, I need your help. Please let me know. Thanks.

Okay, I think I must add a few details before to make my problem clear enough.

The "table number 2" is NOT A REAL TABLE. It is GENERATED from data stored in table number 1. As you can see there in "table number 1" data that 'name', 'position', and 'room' will be "table header" in "table number 2". I hope that was clear enough.

Comment: ehh, why didn't you just have name, room, and position columns in the original table?

Comment: Valueid = autoincrement, formid identify the form from where data is submitted, submissionid tells us that the same number belongs to the same set of submission.

Comment: we get it. we just wonder why table one isn't layed out more like table two to begin with. basically your database is not normalized, which is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a query to give you the data displayed how you've requested, you could use the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sd.SubmissionId
   , sdName.FieldValue AS Name
   , sdPosition.FieldValue AS Position
   , sdRoom.FieldValue AS Room
FROM Storage_Det AS sd
LEFT JOIN Storage_Det AS sdName ON sd.SubmissionId = sdName.SubmissionId
   AND sdName.FieldName = 'Name'
LEFT JOIN Storage_Det AS sdPosition ON sd.SubmissionId = sdPosition.SubmissionId
   AND sdPosition.FieldName = 'Position'
LEFT JOIN Storage_Det AS sdRoom ON sd.SubmissionId = sdRoom.SubmissionId
   AND sdRoom.FieldName = 'Room'
```

Comment: Thank you guys for answering me, I took @Adam Wenger 's answer for his simple, yet powerful solution. Case closed!

Answer (score 1):

Now that I better understand your question here is one way:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE  `table2` (
`submissionid` INT NOT NULL ,
`name` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`position` VARCHAR( 50 ) NULL ,
`room` VARCHAR( 50 ) NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;

ALTER TABLE  `table2` 
ADD UNIQUE (
`submissionid` ,
`name` ,
`position` ,
`room`
);

insert table2 (submissionid, name) select submissionid, fieldvalue from table1 where fieldname='name'; 
update table2 set position = (select fieldvalue from table1 where fieldname='position' and table1.submissionid = table2.submissionid); 
update  table2 set room = (select fieldvalue from table1 where fieldname='room' and table1.submissionid = table2.submissionid);   


select * from table2;
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but you misunderstand what I mean. The table number 2 is GENERATED from table number 1. It's not REAL TABLE. I mean, I need to manipulate table number 1 so that it will display "table number 2".

Comment: ah ok I did misunderstand, I'll try over and get back

Answer (score 0):

First, group all of your data for a certain `submissionid` like so (assuming the very basic mysql API):

```
$sIdGroup = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
{
    if ( !isset( $sIdGroup[ $row[ "submissionid" ] ] ) )
    {
        $sIdGroup[ $row[ "submissionid" ] ] = array();
    }

    $sIdGroup[ $row[ "submissionid" ] ][ $row[ "fieldname" ] ] = $row[ "fieldvalue" ];  // Save the value for the current field
}
```

Now display, first the column names:

```
echo( '<table><tr><td>submissionid</td>' );

// Get the first row in $sIdGroup (i'm assuming 1 is not always the first index)

reset( $sIdGroup );
$firstSubmissionId = key( $sIdGroup );

foreach ( $sIdGroup[ $firstSubmissionId ] as $key => $dummy )
{
    echo( "<td>$key</td>" );
}
```

Now the data:

```
echo( '</tr>' );

foreach ( $sIdGroup as $submissionId => $data )
{
    echo( "<tr><td>$submissionId</td>" );
    foreach ( $data as $key => $value )
    {
        echo( "<td>$value</td>" );
    }
    echo( '</tr>' );
}

echo( '</table>' );
```